# Compare 2 dataframes and get values for row based on query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes: I want to take out values from df2 and append in column in df1 for df1.id = df2.id and df1.name = df2.name

df1:

```
id  name    price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4
1   a               
2   b
```

df2:

```
id  name    price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4
1   a       10      11      12      11
2   b       11      44      22      55
3   c       76      56      45      34
```

output:

```
id  name    price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4
1   a       10      11      12      11
2   b       11      44      22      55
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all `id`, `name` combinations from `df1` are present in `df2` (as in the provided example), just take a subset of `df2` with a match in `df1`:

```
df2.merge(df1[['id', 'name']])
```

Output:

```
   id name  price_1  price_2  price_3  price_4
0   1    a       10       11       12       11
1   2    b       11       44       22       55
```

Comment: Actually for df2, I am getting query result from db. I have
id1, name1
id1, name2
id1, name3
.
In the second iteration I am getting
id2, name1
id2, name2

I want to append price 1,2,3,4, in the original df

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you provide an example with what you actually get from the database on both iterations and what you want to get as the combined result?

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718450/compare-2-dfs-and-append-values-in-df1-based-on-query-in-df2

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge:

```
df1[['id','name']].merge(df2, on=['id','name'], how='left')
```