# Compare 2 dfs and append values in df1 based on query in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes: I want to take out values from df2 and append values of price_1, price_2, price_3, price_4 for each iteration of getting data from db (in df2) in df1 for matching df1.id = df2.id and df1.name = df2.name

df1:

```
id  name   tag    price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4
1   a      a1         
1   b      b1
1   c      c1
2   x      d1
2   y      e1
2   z      a1
```

df2(results form db):

```
1st iteration
id  name   tag  price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4  discount
1   a      x1   10      11      12      11       Y
1   b      x2   11      44      22      55       Y
1   c      x3   76      56      45      34       N

2nd iteration
id  name   tag  price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4  discount
2   x      x2   10      11      12      11       N
2   y      x5   11      44      22      55       Y
2   z      x6   76      56      45      34       N
```

output:

```
df1 (after 1st iteration)
id  name   tag    price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4
1   a      a1     10      11      12      11
1   b      b1     11      44      22      55
1   c      c1     76      56      45      34
2   x       
2   y       
2   z       

df1 (after 2nd iteration)
id  name   tag    price_1 price_2 price_3 price_4
1   a      a1     10      11      12      11
1   b      b1     11      44      22      55
1   c      c1     76      56      45      34
2   x      d1     10      11      12      11
2   y      e1     11      44      22      55
2   z      a1     76      56      45      34
```

loop:

```
grouped = df1.groupby('id')
    
    for i,groups in grouped:
        df2 = sql(i) #goes to sql to fetch details for df1.id
        sql_df = df2.name.unique()
        dd = groups.name
        if (set(sql_df) == set(sql_df) & set(dd)) & (set(dd) == set(sql_df) & set(dd)):
            print ("ID:", i, "Names Match: Y")
            for df2 in iter:
                df4 = pd.DataFrame()
                df_temp = df1[['id', 'name']].merge(df2, on = ['id', 'name'])
                df4 = df4.append(df_temp, ignore_index = True)
        else:
            print("ID:", i, "Names Match: N")
```

I don't need the `tag` and `discount`columns from `df2`, I just need to compare if `name` is equal in both df1 and df22. If yes, then take all the price_1/2/3/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) for each iteration only merged rows by default inner join:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame()
grouped = df1.groupby('id')
    
    for i,groups in grouped:
        df2 = sql(i) #goes to sql to fetch details for df1.id
        sql_df = df2.name.unique()
        dd = groups.name
        if (set(sql_df) == set(sql_df) & set(dd)) & (set(dd) == set(sql_df) & set(dd)):
            print ("ID:", i, "Names Match: Y")
            df_temp = (df1[['id', 'name', 'tag']].merge(df2.drop('tag', axis=1), 
                                                        on = ['id', 'name']))
            df4 = df4.append(df_temp, ignore_index = True)
        else:
            print("ID:", i, "Names Match: N")
```

Comment: Its throwing this error:
'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: @sanchitkhanna26 - how are update data in df2? In some loop?

Comment: Yes, they're in a loop

Comment: @sanchitkhanna26 - If problem implemented my solution to loop, can you edit question with loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220910/discussion-between-sanchitkhanna26-and-jezrael).